Ufrag changing between creating answer and setting local description (android)
In WebRTC on Android, I am creating an answer in response to an offer, and setting the local description off the back of this.
With the recommended method, the local description is set identically to the answer EXCEPT the ufrag and pwd are changed. This means the remote peer does not have the correct credentials and communication cannot proceed.
Using the 'munged' method and directly supplying the description works around this problem but is apparently highly discouraged.
Can anyone explain the logic behind this to me?
@Override
public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Local answer created:");
    Log.d(TAG, sessionDescription.description);

    // setLocalDescription with just an observer
    // in this the description can change
    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(this);
    // setLocalDesciption with an observer and a SessionDescription (munged)
    // this is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED
    //peerConnection.setLocalDescription(this, sessionDescription);
    Log.d(TAG, "Local description set");

    signaling.onLocalAnswer(sessionDescription);
}

@Override
public void onSetSuccess() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Set description was successful");
    Log.d(TAG, "Local description currently:" +
            peerConnection.getLocalDescription().description);
}

If details are required I will put them in comments below. Thanks.

I realise you could signal the answer in onSetSuccess, allowing the description to change, but I still don't see the benefit.

That is definetly not the expected behavior and sounds like a bug.

One benefit is that it forces signaling the answer in onSetSuccess, so if there is some reason the local description could not be set then the remote peer will not have an invalid answer.
I can't find the exact protocol description at the moment on whether it says to set the description to the answer generated or set the answer to the description generated.
